# How do I generate OpenGL ES2 compatible files with glLoadGen?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, emscripten

I am using [glLoadGen](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Home) to generate a header/source pair to load extensions in OpenGL. pretty much what glew does.

This works fine and I have generated a 3.2 core context, but when compiling for the web with Emscripten I need my GL code to be Open GL ES2 compatible, and those 3.2 files from glLoadGen are causing errors since they load functions not compatible with ES2.

I tried to look in the documentation and even the source code of glLoadGen to see how to create ES2 compatible files, but I didn't find anything, and posting the question to their issue tracker [here](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/issue/67/how-to-generate-gl-es2-files) yielded no answers yet.

So is there anyone here who would know how to use glLoadGen to generate OpenGL ES2 compatible files so that I can compile with emscripten?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a basic approximation it is possible to alter specs/glspec.lua (using regex) to mark every compatible-profile feature to be compatible for OpenGL 2.1. Then fixing assertion that only OpenGL >= 3.0 can have profiles allows to generate "core" 2.1 profile w/o features deprecated in 3.2, resulting in somewhat close enough to OpenGL ES 2.0 without extensions.